# Route whole traffic incomming on second Ethernetadapter through OpenVPN TUN-connection

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, bridging

At home I'm running a little PC (Debian Jessie) as a NAS and some kind of a monitoring device. This PC got two bridged Ethernet ports. One is connected to a switch (`eth1`) where all other devices are plugged in and the other one is connected with my router (`eth0`).

On most of my devices there is some OpenVPN client running.
Now I'm trying to establish the VPN-connection directly on my NAS-PC, so there is no need to configure every device for it's own.
But the problem is I can't establish a `TAP`-connection to the VPN-server, only `TUN`-connections. (If the server would accept `TAP`, I could try to bridge `eth1` with `tap0`)

Is there any other possibility, besides bridging (only possible with `TAP`), to direct the whole traffic of `eth1` via the VPN-connection (`TUN`)?

thanks

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to make your Debian Jesse PC a router for all the devices on your network .. but instead of simply passing packets to the upstream router you want to send all packets to a VPN server ?

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is I can't establish a `TAP`-connection to the VPN-server, only `TUN`-connections.

You **cannot** mix `TUN` and `TAP` Mode .. They are **mutually Exclusive**.  If you run `TUN` on your server you **must** run `TUN` on your client and likewise with `TAP`

I **cannot** make this any clearer .. You must run the same device on both ends .. **Full stop**

Comment: I know. My problem is the server only accepts TUN. Is there any other chance to route the traffic, incoming on eth1, through the VPN-connection. Till now I bridged eth0 and eth1, so I could monitor the passing traffic. The monitoring isn't that important, when I'm able to use the VPN-connection.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword is `routing`. (thanks to @dotvotdot)

I achieved my goal by running a OpenVPN client and a DHCP server on my NAS. Also I set the IP of eth1 to static.

My current routing rules:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE -m comment --comment "Use VPN IP for eth0"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE -m comment --comment "Use VPN IP for tun0"

iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.101.0/24 -i eth1 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j REJECT -m comment --comment "Block traffic from clients to eth0"

iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.101.0/24 -i eth1 -o tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow only traffic from clients to tun0"`

source: http://blog.frd.mn/raspberry-pi-vpn-gateway/